# Run Python script in PHP

Tags: php, python

## My goal

is to run my python script using PHP.
I have a start button on the front-end when I click on that button. It start a service.

---

## Try #1

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python ".public_path().'/python/start_clientsim.py 2>&1');
$result = exec($command);
```

Still not working

---

## Try #2

```
$command = escapeshellcmd("python ".public_path().'/python/start_clientsim.py 2>&1');
$result = shell_exec($command);
```

Still not working

---

## Try #3

`chmod a+x start_clientsim.py`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 bheng  staff  1154 May 17 19:42 start_clientsim.py
```

Re-tried still same result

---

## Try #4

*If I execute the command directly*

`python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/python‌/start_clientsim.py 2>&1`

I got it to run `perfectly` fine.

[image]

---

## Try #5

*I tried with different python simple script*

`python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/python/print.py`

**print.py**

```
# This program prints Hello, world!

print('Hello, world!')
```

I got

result: "Hello, world!"

---

## Question

How would one go about and debug this further  ?

Comment: What's the value of `public_path()` ? You can try to provide the full path of the python binary, to find it, use, `which python`. What's the output of `echo "python ".public_path()."/python/start_clientsim.py 2>&1"` ?  does this output runs without errors if pasted on the shell?

Comment: did you try to start the same script from the user running your webserver? It could be www-data, httpd, apache etc

Comment: @PedroLobito : `python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/python/start_clientsim.py 2>&1`

Comment: if you run `python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/python‌​/start_clientsim.py 2>&1`  on the shell does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work. It's SSH into the VM and start a service. Perfectly. I don't doubt my python. I doubt the way I trigger it using PHP. I don't know how to debug to see why it is not working.

Comment: Sometimes `exec`, `system`, etc are disabled . Check if `is_callable("exec")`

Comment: @t.m.adam : Are you talking about `exec` , `system` in python ? or PHP ?

Comment: @Marat : I would like to try your suggestion. Should I `chmod` my script to a certain permission or something ?

Comment: PHP . You can get a list of disabled functions with `ini_get('disable_functions')`

Comment: @t.m.adam : What should I do with that ? I tried `echo(ini_get('disable_functions')) ; ` I got nothing. I tried `dd(ini_get('disable_functions'))`

Comment: That means `exec` is available . It's propably about permissons, like @Marat suggested. Use `chmod 0755`

Comment: @ihue to check if this is the case you need to find out the username. Then change to the desired user terminal (`sudo su <username>`) and run the desired command. If it works, then you can either chmod 755, or chown/chgrp service script to the <username>, or add username to the script group - there are many ways to give exec permissions

Comment: If you guys have any other suggestions for me - please keep them coming. I needed them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to write a PHP module in C that basically acts as a gateway to the python interpreter and then just feed everything through that. This would be much more efficient and is what I would do.

Comment: Thank-you answering, but I am not a C expert, but I'll look into it though if I got nothing in the next couple days. :)

Comment: I mean what you basically do is make a PHP module in C that talks with the python DLL file or whatever much like the .exe file of the python interpreter would. Might need to take a look at the python source code to see how the .exe talks with the DLL though :). Or you could just invoke the execute commands in the PHP module but I dont recommend that the one I mentioned first would be much better

Comment: Obviously if we are talking linux then .SO file.

Comment: English please. jk. Your suggestion is very technical for me, and I completely respect that. But I just don't know where to start. I'll start with thank-you !

Comment: I mean ive only ever written a hello world PHP module. But these things aren't designed for people not to use them. They are designed well and I am sure you could pull something off this way. Might be overkill for what your doing and no problem :)